# Help setting up Dust sensor with Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors

So I wired Sharp Dust Sensor with Arduino Mega with below fritzing:

[image]

the connector cable only connects to the dust sensor as you can seee the image below:

[image]
however looking at other example projects the same dust sensor has wiring inverted. I followed the hookup and the code as given here: https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/index.php?title=Dust_Sensor-_GP2Y1010AU0F

but I get the result without having to connect the green wire to **A0** and Yellow wire connected to **D2**

```
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 346.00 - Voltage: 1.69 - Dust Density: 0.19
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 394.00 - Voltage: 1.92 - Dust Density: 0.23
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 398.00 - Voltage: 1.94 - Dust Density: 0.23
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 408.00 - Voltage: 1.99 - Dust Density: 0.24
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 433.00 - Voltage: 2.11 - Dust Density: 0.26
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 468.00 - Voltage: 2.29 - Dust Density: 0.29
```

if I connect the yellow to **A0** And green to **D2**  then I get below result.

```
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1023.00 - Voltage: 5.00 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1020.00 - Voltage: 4.98 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1020.00 - Voltage: 4.98 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1023.00 - Voltage: 5.00 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1023.00 - Voltage: 5.00 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1022.00 - Voltage: 4.99 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1023.00 - Voltage: 5.00 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1020.00 - Voltage: 4.98 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1023.00 - Voltage: 5.00 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1023.00 - Voltage: 5.00 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1022.00 - Voltage: 4.99 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1023.00 - Voltage: 5.00 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1023.00 - Voltage: 5.00 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1023.00 - Voltage: 5.00 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1023.00 - Voltage: 5.00 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1023.00 - Voltage: 5.00 - Dust Density: 0.75
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 1005.00 - Voltage: 4.91 - Dust Density: 0.73
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 952.00 - Voltage: 4.65 - Dust Density: 0.69
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 712.00 - Voltage: 3.48 - Dust Density: 0.49
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 631.00 - Voltage: 3.08 - Dust Density: 0.42
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 559.00 - Voltage: 2.73 - Dust Density: 0.36
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 504.00 - Voltage: 2.46 - Dust Density: 0.32
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 463.00 - Voltage: 2.26 - Dust Density: 0.28
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 431.00 - Voltage: 2.10 - Dust Density: 0.26
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 409.00 - Voltage: 2.00 - Dust Density: 0.24
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 430.00 - Voltage: 2.10 - Dust Density: 0.26
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 413.00 - Voltage: 2.02 - Dust Density: 0.24
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 377.00 - Voltage: 1.84 - Dust Density: 0.21
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 453.00 - Voltage: 2.21 - Dust Density: 0.28
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 368.00 - Voltage: 1.80 - Dust Density: 0.21
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 367.00 - Voltage: 1.79 - Dust Density: 0.20
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 364.00 - Voltage: 1.78 - Dust Density: 0.20
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 361.00 - Voltage: 1.76 - Dust Density: 0.20
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 357.00 - Voltage: 1.74 - Dust Density: 0.20
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 356.00 - Voltage: 1.74 - Dust Density: 0.20
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 358.00 - Voltage: 1.75 - Dust Density: 0.20
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 357.00 - Voltage: 1.74 - Dust Density: 0.20
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 345.00 - Voltage: 1.68 - Dust Density: 0.19
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 309.00 - Voltage: 1.51 - Dust Density: 0.16
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 375.00 - Voltage: 1.83 - Dust Density: 0.21
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 395.00 - Voltage: 1.93 - Dust Density: 0.23
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 421.00 - Voltage: 2.06 - Dust Density: 0.25
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 441.00 - Voltage: 2.15 - Dust Density: 0.27
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 343.00 - Voltage: 1.67 - Dust Density: 0.18
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 352.00 - Voltage: 1.72 - Dust Density: 0.19
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 341.00 - Voltage: 1.67 - Dust Density: 0.18
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 339.00 - Voltage: 1.66 - Dust Density: 0.18
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 342.00 - Voltage: 1.67 - Dust Density: 0.18
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 307.00 - Voltage: 1.50 - Dust Density: 0.15
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 335.00 - Voltage: 1.64 - Dust Density: 0.18
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 343.00 - Voltage: 1.67 - Dust Density: 0.18
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 348.00 - Voltage: 1.70 - Dust Density: 0.19
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 351.00 - Voltage: 1.71 - Dust Density: 0.19
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 355.00 - Voltage: 1.73 - Dust Density: 0.19
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 359.00 - Voltage: 1.75 - Dust Density: 0.20
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 456.00 - Voltage: 2.23 - Dust Density: 0.28
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 477.00 - Voltage: 2.33 - Dust Density: 0.30
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 392.00 - Voltage: 1.91 - Dust Density: 0.23
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 443.00 - Voltage: 2.16 - Dust Density: 0.27
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 419.00 - Voltage: 2.05 - Dust Density: 0.25
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 379.00 - Voltage: 1.85 - Dust Density: 0.21
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 292.00 - Voltage: 1.43 - Dust Density: 0.14
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 341.00 - Voltage: 1.67 - Dust Density: 0.18
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 311.00 - Voltage: 1.52 - Dust Density: 0.16
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 307.00 - Voltage: 1.50 - Dust Density: 0.15
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 284.00 - Voltage: 1.39 - Dust Density: 0.14
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 322.00 - Voltage: 1.57 - Dust Density: 0.17
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 309.00 - Voltage: 1.51 - Dust Density: 0.16
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 331.00 - Voltage: 1.62 - Dust Density: 0.17
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 326.00 - Voltage: 1.59 - Dust Density: 0.17
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 304.00 - Voltage: 1.48 - Dust Density: 0.15
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 340.00 - Voltage: 1.66 - Dust Density: 0.18
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 385.00 - Voltage: 1.88 - Dust Density: 0.22
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 399.00 - Voltage: 1.95 - Dust Density: 0.23
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 420.00 - Voltage: 2.05 - Dust Density: 0.25
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 448.00 - Voltage: 2.19 - Dust Density: 0.27
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 479.00 - Voltage: 2.34 - Dust Density: 0.30
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 424.00 - Voltage: 2.07 - Dust Density: 0.25
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 438.00 - Voltage: 2.14 - Dust Density: 0.26
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 438.00 - Voltage: 2.14 - Dust Density: 0.26
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 330.00 - Voltage: 1.61 - Dust Density: 0.17
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 352.00 - Voltage: 1.72 - Dust Density: 0.19
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 350.00 - Voltage: 1.71 - Dust Density: 0.19
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 343.00 - Voltage: 1.67 - Dust Density: 0.18
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 314.00 - Voltage: 1.53 - Dust Density: 0.16
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 305.00 - Voltage: 1.49 - Dust Density: 0.15
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 306.00 - Voltage: 1.49 - Dust Density: 0.15
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 317.00 - Voltage: 1.55 - Dust Density: 0.16
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 341.00 - Voltage: 1.67 - Dust Density: 0.18
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 361.00 - Voltage: 1.76 - Dust Density: 0.20
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 384.00 - Voltage: 1.88 - Dust Density: 0.22
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 417.00 - Voltage: 2.04 - Dust Density: 0.25
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 435.00 - Voltage: 2.12 - Dust Density: 0.26
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 446.00 - Voltage: 2.18 - Dust Density: 0.27
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 310.00 - Voltage: 1.51 - Dust Density: 0.16
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 462.00 - Voltage: 2.26 - Dust Density: 0.28
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 432.00 - Voltage: 2.11 - Dust Density: 0.26
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 391.00 - Voltage: 1.91 - Dust Density: 0.22
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 339.00 - Voltage: 1.66 - Dust Density: 0.18
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 324.00 - Voltage: 1.58 - Dust Density: 0.17
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 306.00 - Voltage: 1.49 - Dust Density: 0.15
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 294.00 - Voltage: 1.44 - Dust Density: 0.14
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 283.00 - Voltage: 1.38 - Dust Density: 0.13
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 274.00 - Voltage: 1.34 - Dust Density: 0.13
```

If I connect the green wire to **A0** and Yellow wire to **D2** I get below result

```
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 0.00 - Voltage: 0.00 - Dust Density: -0.10
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 0.00 - Voltage: 0.00 - Dust Density: -0.10
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 0.00 - Voltage: 0.00 - Dust Density: -0.10
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 0.00 - Voltage: 0.00 - Dust Density: -0.10
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 0.00 - Voltage: 0.00 - Dust Density: -0.10
Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 0.00 - Voltage: 0.00 - Dust Density: -0.10
```

I am not really sure whether I am getting the correct result or not, and have I hooked up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The outline diagram shows the connection order:

[image]

As you can see from the image in the second row pin 1 is closest to the edge of the unit. In your image that is red.  So following those down and matching them to the "Terminal Configuration":

1. V-LED = Red (Connect to 5V via resistor)
2. LED-GND = Black (GND)
3. LED = Yellow (D2)
4. S-GND = White (GND)
5. Vo = Green (A0)
6. Vcc = Blue (Connect direct to 5V)

Comment: connecting this way gives this result: 
`Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 0.00 - Voltage: 0.00 - Dust Density: -0.10`

`Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 0.00 - Voltage: 0.00 - Dust Density: -0.10`

Comment: The way you wired it before may have killed the IR LED through over-current...

Comment: is IR LED replaceable manually by soldering ?

Comment: If you can get to it, possibly. Unlikely though for a novice.